# Failed to build after upgrade to flutter 1.2

Tags: flutter, dart

```
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_datetime_picker-1.3.8/lib/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart:6:28: Error: Type 'DiagnosticableMixin' not found.
class DatePickerTheme with DiagnosticableMixin {                        
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                          
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_datetime_picker-1.3.8/lib/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart:6:7: Error: The type 'DiagnosticableMixin' can't be mixed in.
class DatePickerTheme with DiagnosticableMixin {                        
      ^                                                                 
                                                                        
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                        
* Where:                                                                
Script '/home/tfradebe/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 896
                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.              
> Process 'command '/home/tfradebe/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
                                                                        
* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
                                                                        
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              
                                                                        
BUILD FAILED in 28s                                                     
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        29.1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Created a new project with flutter create, added dependencies to pubspec.yml and paste my lib folder from previous project. Still no luck.

Comment: Hey there, the flutter_datetime_picker was updated yesterday to v1.4.0 with a fix for this

Answer (score 2):

There is a fix in progress to solve this issue that affected many plugins. In the meantime, you can include the reference to `flutter_datetime_picker` like this

```yaml
flutter_datetime_picker:
  git:
    url: https://github.com/ditheshthegreat/flutter_datetime_picker # Repo
    ref: patch-1 # Branch name
```

[This](https://github.com/Realank/flutter_datetime_picker/issues/155#issuecomment-664443209) is the github related ticket

Comment: There was a [fix](https://github.com/Realank/flutter_datetime_picker/commit/8447689960f2913cbf77d2f57574bf2035a108c5) for this in the main branch of the flutter_datetime_picker package github yesterday that is backwards compatible with flutter, I would suggest having the url point to the [main](https://github.com/Realank/flutter_datetime_picker/) branch